# css position static element in relative element

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css.
I've some questions about position "static" and "relative". 
When the "static" element places in the "relative" one, how does the margin property work?
The code is following.

```css
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.top{
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:20px;
 }
  
.back{
  background-color:#eee;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div class="top">Top text </div>
</div>
```

My question is that "top" div has the margin-top 20px.
The "back" div is "relative" and hasn't margin.
But why does "back" div have the margin same as the "top" div?

---

Comment: position: relative doesn't change how margins work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is "margin collapse" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> **Parent and first/last child** - If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Comment: How very odd that MDN's link to its BFC article is formatted so differently. I wonder if it's an editing mistake.